# split String twice and put it in a HashMap

Tags: string, rust, split, hashmap

I have a String `atp.Status="draft";pureMM.maxOccurs="1";pureMM.minOccurs="1";xml.attribute="true"` and want to split it twice and insert it into a HashMap. For the first split I use `;` and for the second `=`. It should look like this.

```
appinfo {
     atp.Status: "draft",
     pureMM.maxOccurs: "1",
     pureMM.minOccurs: "1",
     xml.attribute: "true",
}
```

This is my code:

```
let mut appinfo: HashMap<String,String> = HashMap::new();
let text = r#"atp.Status="draft";pureMM.maxOccurs="1";pureMM.minOccurs="1";xml.attribute="true""#;
appinfo = HashMap::from_iter(text.split(";").map(|a|a.split_once("=").unwrap()));
```

I get:

```
   = note: expected struct `HashMap<String, String, RandomState>`
              found struct `HashMap<&str, &str, _>`
```

I have already tried all possible variants and combinations in map and outside with `to_string()` , `into_iter()` or `collect()`. My only working solution was to change the type of `HashMap` to `<&str, &str>` but I don't want that.
How can I turn the two string splices into normal strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `to_string()` on both parts of the `split_once`:

```rust
let text = r#"atp.Status="draft";pureMM.maxOccurs="1";pureMM.minOccurs="1";xml.attribute="true""#;
let appinfo = HashMap::from_iter(text.split(";").map(|a| {
    let (key, value) = a.split_once("=").unwrap();
    (key.to_string(), value.to_string())
}));
```